# getting the heading of a selected text in word

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, ms-word

I am working With Microsoft Word VBA,macros,.net
My question : Is there way to get sub-topic and master-topic that precedes a selected body text ?

Here is an example:

- **Master topic (level 1)**
- **sub-topic 1 (level 2)**

  - body text a
  - body text b body text c
- **sub-topic 2 (level 2)**

  - body text d
  - body text e
- **Other MISC topics (level 2)** body text f body text g body text h

Here if **bodytext e** is selected I would like to run a macro that gives a result text
**Master topic:sub-topic 1**.
I have tried with `range,parent ,Scope.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber)` etc but nothing seem to work!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> 'By Dhiraj Bajracharya '2010 Sub
> getHeaddingsRecursive(arange As Range)
> If MainHeading <> "" Then Exit Sub On
> Error GoTo err
>     If Subheading = "" Then
>         If arange.Paragraphs(1).OutlineLevel =
> WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel2 Then
>             Subheading = arange.Text
>             Exit Sub
>         End If
>     End If
>     If arange.Paragraphs(1).OutlineLevel =
> WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel1 Then
>          MainHeading = arange.Text
>     End If    Call getHeaddingsRecursive(arange.Previous(wdParagraph,
> 1)) err: End Sub
```

This recursive function works and the output is stored  in heading and subheading.

Answer (score 0):

paragraph levels are part of an enum.  All you have to do is keep track of what paragraph level you are at and then grab sub level items.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application wrd = new Application();
        Document d;
        Documents docs = wrd.Documents;
        object readOnly = true;
        object fileName = @"C:\Users\v-chrha\Desktop\text doc.docx";
        object missing = Missing.Value;
        d = docs.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref  missing, ref  missing
            , ref  missing, ref  missing, ref  missing, ref  missing, ref  missing
            , ref  missing, ref  missing, ref  missing, ref  missing, ref  missing, ref  missing);

        int previousLevel = 0;
        int currentLevel = 0;
        foreach (Paragraph p in d.Paragraphs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Paragraph: {0}\nLevel: {1}", p.Range.Text, p.p.OutlineLevel.ToString());
            switch (p.OutlineLevel)
            {
                case WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel1:
                    currentLevel = 1;
                    break;
                case WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel2:
                    currentLevel = 2;
                    break;
                case WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel3:
                    currentLevel = 3;
                    break;
                case WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel4:
                    currentLevel = 4;
                    break;
                case WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel5:
                    currentLevel = 5;
                    break;
                case WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel6:
                    currentLevel = 6;
                    break;
                case WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel7:
                    currentLevel = 7;
                    break;
                case WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel8:
                    currentLevel = 8;
                    break;
                case WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel9:
                    currentLevel = 9;
                    break;
                case WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevelBodyText:
                    currentLevel = 10;
                    break;
            }
            if (currentLevel > previousLevel)
                Console.WriteLine("with previous");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("not with previous");
            previousLevel = currentLevel;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
        docs = null;
        d.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        d = null;
        wrd.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        wrd = null;


    }
}
```

Comment: I'd even venutre to say that the enum value could be converted to an integer just the same. see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237890.aspx